# NSFetchedResultsController with one-to-many relationship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

This is something i just can't figure out working with Core Data. I want to work with an NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate and the usual code i've seen so far is easy to understand but always based on a one entity model. So you want to show in your table all the "events", you do a fetch request on the Event entity and there, you are set to go.

The thing is, my model is:

```
City (one-to-one) Company (one-to-many) Employees
```

My table would need to show the employees, but the fetch would have to be based on the City, in order to retrieve the Company and then the Employees, right? I'm completely lost at this, i just don't see how to do the fetch.

Because if i fetch City or Company and i put Employees in an NSMutableSet, don't i loose all the authomatic UITableViewController syncing? For instance, if i do it like this, i will be unable to do something like

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = 
        [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

Comment: Beware of NSFecthedResultController + Sections I have bad memories with it, it was seriously bugged (in apple sdk) before iOS3.2. After 3.2 I think that even improved, it still had some issues. I didn't tried with recent versions. I'm avoiding NSFetchedResultController as possible now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You data model should have reciprocal relationships such that when you fetch any particular object, you have immediate access to all related objects.

In your case, a data model with reciprocal relationships would look something like:

```
City{
    company<-->Company.city
}

Company{
    city<-->City.company
    employees<-->>Employee.company
}

Employee{
    company<<-->Company.employees
}
```

So, if you have an `Employee` object, you find the company with `self.company` and the city by `self.company.city` (in most case the actual `self` is unnecessary and I use it for illustration purposes.) If you have a `Company` object, you find employees in `self.employees` and the city in `self.city`. If you have a `City` object you would find all the employees with `self.company.employees`.

Relationships are what actually create the object graph at the heart of Core Data. You use fetches to find one group of objects in the graph and then you "walk" the relationships outward from those objects to find all the related data. It is the reciprocal relationships that make it possible to go back and forth across the relationships in both directions.

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never.

Use a predicate

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ProvinceToCounty == %@)", selectedObject];
```

Go it from this link, http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-core-data-uitableview-drill-down/

If you're planning to make a generic class and make this work for different parent-child entities, make sure to delete the cache name of you NSFetchedResultsController.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be fetching the "Company" managed object with a filter on the City attribute or the Company Name attribute, or both.  If you have set up the one-to-many relationship between Company and Employees, then your Company managed object should have a NSSet property that has all of the employee objects that you will need for your list.

Comment: That's what i did so far, but in that way is miss all the out-of-the-box syncin with UITableViewController (having it listen to the NSMutableSet changes, instead of just the fetchrequest).For example, i will not be able to use it in tableView numberOfRowsInSection:

Comment: I use the NSFetchedResultsController to manage my UITableViewControllers.  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Yes, i know that. What i don't know is how to use it in this case, when the entity is inside another one.

Comment: I think your EntityDescription should be "Employees" and your Predicate should traverse the relationship to filter properly.  So, NSPredicate *searchType = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"employee.company.city=%d", cityId];